# How to create a parallel loop using aiohttp or asyncio in Python?

Tags: python, rethinkdb, python-asyncio, rethinkdb-python, aiohttp

I would like to use rethinkdb .changes() feature to push some messages to  users. The messages should send without any requests from the users.

I am using rethinkdb with aiohttp and websockets. How it works:

1. User sends message
2. Server puts it into rethinkdb
3. What I need: an additional loop uses rethinkdb `.changes` function to send updates to connected users

This is how I initiate the application:

```
@asyncio.coroutine
def init(loop):
    app = Application(loop=loop)
    app['sockets'] = []
    app['susers'] = []
    app.router.add_route('GET', '/', wshandler)
    handler = app.make_handler()
    srv = yield from loop.create_server(handler, '127.0.0.1', 9080)
    print("Server started at http://127.0.0.1:9080")
    return app, srv, handler
```

In the `wshandler` I have a loop, which processes incoming messages:

```
@asyncio.coroutine
def wshandler(request):
    resp = WebSocketResponse()
    if not resp.can_prepare(request):
        return Response(
            body=bytes(json.dumps({"error_code": 401}), 'utf-8'),
            content_type='application/json'
        )
    yield from resp.prepare(request)
    request.app['sockets'].append(resp)
    print('Someone connected')
    while True:
        msg = yield from resp.receive()
        if msg.tp == MsgType.text:
            runCommand(msg, resp, request)
        else:
            break
    request.app['sockets'].remove(resp)
    print('Someone disconnected.')
    return resp
```

How to create a second loop sending messages to the same pool of opened connections? How to make it thread-safe?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26270681/can-an-asyncio-event-loop-run-in-the-background-without-suspending-the-python-in

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to achieve my goal without creating threads? If I use them, a new thread will be created for every connection, but I would like to keep everything light. Rethinkdb's `.changes()` returns generator, so it must be possible to avoid using threads.

Comment: I am not familiar with Rethinkdb, but in general it should not be necessary to use threads to have concurrent loops in asyncio. Within your While True loop you simply chain additional coroutines (using yield from), or if you need more "parallel" type behaviour, then use async() / ensure_future() and asyncio will then juggle between the two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking, you should *try* to avoid threads as much as a possible whenever running an event loop.

Unfortunately `rethinkdb` does not support `asyncio` out-of-the-box, but it does support the [Tornado & Twisted](http://rethinkdb.com/docs/async-connections/#python-with-tornado-or-twisted) frameworks.
So, you could [bridge](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/asyncio.html) Tornado & `asyncio` and make it work without using threads.

*Edit*:

As Andrew pointed out `rethinkdb` **does** support `asyncio`. After [2.1.0](https://github.com/rethinkdb/rethinkdb/releases/tag/v2.1.0-1) you can presumably do:

```
rethinkdb.set_loop_type("asyncio")
```

And then in your web handlers:

```
res = await rethinkdb.table(tbl).changes().run(connection)
while await res.fetch_next():
   ...
```

Comment: Looking on https://github.com/rethinkdb/rethinkdb/tree/next/drivers/python/rethinkdb/asyncio_net it does, at least on master.

Comment: Yes okay, it was added in [2.1.0](https://github.com/rethinkdb/rethinkdb/releases/tag/v2.1.0-1).