# Trigger Background Task With POST request in Django

Tags: python, django, celery, python-asyncio

I want to trigger a **background task** (just trigger, not require to wait till finish), when user does the POST request. 
I know, I can do it with `celery`. But don't want to add the task in queue, as it has to be triggered immediately. This task can be long running, so after triggering I don't want to hold the POST call and just send response as request received. 
There might be a way using thread, but can I do it with `asyncio` or any other lib in python. 
`Python 3.5 and  Django 2.2  with DRF`

Comment: Check this answer 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/26270790/5375584

Comment: So for my case, I can just go with Threading, No need to use asyncio right?

Comment: Yes. There are quite a few ways you can tackle it, it ultimately depends on what you need to do. Therading, multiprocess , asyncio etc some of the easiest ways. you can also pawn of the heavy work to celeary, huey etc