# How to run twitch bot and app simultaneously

Tags: python, aiohttp, web-development-server, twitch-api

```
if __name__ =='__main__': 
  bot.run()
  web.run_app(app, port=5000)
```

I am trying to run these 2 simultaneously, however, one is blocking the other. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they are both synchronous (no `async` or `await`) then you can use

```py
import threading

threading.Thread(target=bot.run).start()
# or threading.Thread(target=web.run_app, args=(app,), kwargs={"port": 5000"}
```

and then use `threading.Lock` for database operations (https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Lock).

If one is asynchronous, then look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26270681/can-an-asyncio-event-loop-run-in-the-background-without-suspending-the-python-in).